# ¿Es adecuado escribir todo el código JS dentro de un disparador de tipo 'DOMContentLoaded'?

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

Si pretendemos acceder a objetos del DOM antes de que este se cargue podemos tener problemas. ¿Es adecuado escribir TODO el código JS dentro de un eventListener de tipo 'DOMContentLoaded'? Hay algo que sea mas adecuado dejarlo fuera? Disculpad, pero soy principiante y esta es una cuestión que por muy obvia que pueda parecerle a un veterano a me preocupa y confunde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nosé a qué te refieras con `"adecuado"`, pero con DOMContentLoaded, siempre te aseguras de que ha cargado el documento, PERO no completamente porque no toma en cuenta imagenes, ni hojas de estilos, aunque contradictoriamente muchas veces sí funciona, porque la mayoría de veces si carga todo, en cambio load espera que carge absolutamente TODO, como lo dice la MDN:

> Un evento muy diferente - load - debería ser usado solo para detectar
>   una carga completa de la página

```js
;window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",windowMain);

function windowMain(){
  function add(a,b){ return a + b}
  console.log(add(5,5));
}
```

Comment: Cierto, de acuerdo. ¿Crees, pues, recomendable que la ejecución de todo nuestro código se produzca siempre una vez se haya cargado todo el documento con load? Me cubro completamente las espaldas? Gracias!

Comment: Claro, ya que ese es el fin de javascript, interactuar con el documento y hacerlo dinámico.